# Вызов хранимой процедуры из хранимой процедуры не даёт результатов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется две хранимые процедуры - `p1` и `p2`. `p1` возвращает данные из таблицы `Table1` табличного типа `table1_type` с каким-то содержимым, а `p2` просто возвращает то, что вернула `p1`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p1
  @Resp INT OUTPUT
AS 
SET @Resp = 0;
SELECT * FROM Table1;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p2
  @Resp INT OUTPUT
AS 
DECLARE @tmp table1_type;
INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC dbo.p1 @Resp OUTPUT;
SELECT * FROM @tmp;
GO
```

Если сделать следующий запрос

```
DECLARE @tmp dbo.table1_type;
DECLARE @Resp INT;
INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC dbo.p1 @Resp OUTPUT;
SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

то в таблице `@tmp` появится содержимое таблицы `Table1` и переменная `@Resp` станет равна 0. Но если вызвать процедуру `dbo.p2` то она ничего не вернёт (`@tmp` будет пустой) и переменная `@Resp` ничему не будет равна.

```
DECLARE @tmp dbo.table1_type;
DECLARE @Resp INT;
INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC dbo.p2 @Resp OUTPUT;
SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

Почему так происходит и как можно вызывать хранимую процедуру, которая в себе содержит вызов другой хранимой процедуры, чтобы при этом возвращалось то, что ожидается?

Comment: Может это из-за того, что в рабочем примере `DECLARE @tmp dbo.cfgv_type;`, а в нерабочем `DECLARE @tmp table1_type;`?

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin, нет. Это я копировал из рабочего проекта и забыл исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в использовании конструкции `INSERT INTO ... EXEC ...` во вложенной процедуре. Во вложенной процедуре эту конструкцию использовать нельзя. Поэтому, если обойти этот момент и возвращать данные, например, через `OUTPUT` параметры, то всё складывается хорошо. Ответ нашёл здесь http://www.t-sql.ru/post/An_INSERT_EXEC_statement_cannot_be_nested.aspx